# Create popup dialogue box on workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have created a workflow to send an email request to site admin for selected line item (It can be for changes or deletion). As & when I select particular line item to run workflow, it should popup an dialogue box for "Comments/reason" and that comment should be recorded in the email request.

Is it possible ? If yes then How ?

Answer (score 0):

Below can get you started.

1. Create 1 column like StartWorkflow and another to store comments/reason.
2. Create a workflow which will trigger based on condition(like when StartWorkflow is true), use the Comments/Reason column in form email body which you are sending to site admin.Make the startworkflow to false just before workflow ends so that it will not trigger next time.
3. On you custom page where user select line items, Create a popup section with require control to capture reason/comment and a button which will trigger a JS function, update both the above columns with client side code.
4. Once the line item is updated the workflow will trigger and will send mail accordingly.